# Unable to remove index.php

Tags: ee, index, index.php, bluehost

I have been trying to remove the index.php from my website. I have tried everything mentioned on the ee documentation but nothing seemed to work. I also tried to enable force force query string, it didn't work either.

I'm running the website on bluehost and I think maybe the problem is associated with the server? I contacted them and they mentioned that the mod_rewrite apache is running on all their websites just fine. Not sure what the solution to this problem.

this is the same code that I used in my .htaccess file

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /my_site_url.net/

    # Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

    # Directs all EE web requests through the site index file
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
    </IfModule>
```

Comment: I also wanted to mention that I get a blank page

Comment: Why do u use "RewriteBase /my_site_url.net/" ? Do you have  folder my_site_url.net in your public_html and index.php is inside this folder? Did u try "RewriteBase /"

Comment: no I don't have a folder named like that, but I added my site name that's what I meant. I also tried RewriteBase / .. and I also tried to change the $config['uri_protocol'] to PATH_INFO and I also tried REQUEST URI in the config file as mentioned in some of the answers here on the website, but it didn't work at all. What am I possibly missing?

Comment: in any case will be enouth "RewriteBase /" - is not correct to use it like you do (you can read http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase). Try this one http://devot-ee.com/articles/item/simple-htaccess-for-expressionengine-sites, if this code will works, you can try https://gist.github.com/3439374.git. What hosting you use? did you try to add "?" for index.php? like "RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]"

Comment: Thanks for the links, I'll try them. I'm using bluehost and I tried to"?" as well, but it didn't work.

Comment: I used exactly the same code provided in this link.. It didn't work either. Not sure why. Do I need to edit anything on that code in order for it to work?